# React Pass associated data (props) to descendents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement commenting tutorial given on the React.js website but with some extra features. I want to pass associated user data like username and avatar with the comments object. I understand how props can be passed from parents to child components but how do we pass data from Parent -> Child -> Child? or Parent -> subChild ?

Parent CommentBox Component:

```
 <CommentList comments= {this.state.comments} avatar= {this. state. avatar} count={this.state.comments_count} user= {this.state.user} />
```

Comment List Component: (comment list is returns Comment Component)

```
 var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function (comment) {
      <Comment comment={ comment.comment } key={ comment.id } avatar = "how to pass the parent avatar state" count = "how to pass parent count state" />
    });
});
```

How do I access the props into Comment component, which is responsible for rendering individual comments? Note that Comment component is SubChild of CommentBox Component.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just JavaScript, so you can store it in a variable.  There are a number of ways to do this `var self = this`, `var props = this.props`, `var {count,avatar} = this.props` (es6), etc.

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var count = this.props.count;
    var avatar = this.props.avatar
    var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function (comment) {
      <Comment comment={ comment.comment } key={ comment.id } 
               avatar={ avatar } count={ count } />
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate your help :). Silly me :( Actually, I did the same thing, but not inside the render function and was wondering why it's not working. You know, when you are trying something for the first time you get excited and don't notice the basic mistakes. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yep, I do that quite often :-)